# How to add keycloak-admin-client-api in sbt scala project

Tags: scala, sbt, keycloak

I am using sbt 1.2.8 and i am trying to add `keycloak-admin-client`

Here is my `build.sbt`:

```
scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.13.1"
libraryDependencies := {      libraryDependencies.value ++ Seq(
        "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.1.0" % Test,
        "javax.ws.rs" % "javax.ws.rs-api" % "2.0.1",
"org.keycloak" % "keycloak-adapter-core" % "3.3.0.CR2",
        "org.keycloak" % "keycloak-core" % "3.3.0.CR2",
        "org.keycloak" % "keycloak-admin-client" % "12.0.2")
```

i am getting exception

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: junit#junit;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[warn]  :: org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs#jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[warn]  :: org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind#jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[warn]  :: org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet#jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[warn]  :: org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation#jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[warn]  :: javax.activation#activation;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[warn]  :: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[warn]  :: commons-io#commons-io;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[warn]  :: com.github.stephenc.jcip#jcip-annotations;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[warn]  :: org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[warn]  :: org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging-annotations;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[warn]  :: org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging-processor;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[warn]  :: org.glassfish.jaxb#jaxb-runtime;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[warn]  :: com.sun.mail#javax.mail;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[warn]  :: org.apache.james#apache-mime4j;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[warn]  :: com.github.fge#json-patch;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 

[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: junit#junit;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs#jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind#jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet#jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation#jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: javax.activation#activation;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: commons-io#commons-io;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.github.stephenc.jcip#jcip-annotations;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging-annotations;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging-processor;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.glassfish.jaxb#jaxb-runtime;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.sun.mail#javax.mail;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.james#apache-mime4j;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.github.fge#json-patch;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.resolveAndRetrieve(IvyActions.scala:332)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$updateEither$1(IvyActions.scala:208)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withModule$1(Ivy.scala:239)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.$anonfun$withIvy$1(Ivy.scala:204)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:70)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:95)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:80)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:99)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:60)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:50)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:199)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:196)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:238)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:193)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.ivy.IvyDependencyResolution.update(IvyDependencyResolution.scala:20)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:56)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:45)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:93)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:68)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$19(LibraryManagement.scala:106)
[error]     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:106)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:89)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:149)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:120)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask$5(Defaults.scala:2561)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:67)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:278)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: junit#junit;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs#jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind#jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet#jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation#jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: javax.activation#activation;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: commons-io#commons-io;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.github.stephenc.jcip#jcip-annotations;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging-annotations;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging-processor;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.glassfish.jaxb#jaxb-runtime;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.sun.mail#javax.mail;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.james#apache-mime4j;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.github.fge#json-patch;working@yser-Inspiron-7773: not found
[error] Total time: 16 s, completed Jan 27, 2021, 3:22:22 PM
[IJ]sbt:myproject-auth>
```

Comment: Swaheed, did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `libraryDependencies` as suggested at [Managed Dependencies](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Dependencies.html#Managed+Dependencies):

```
scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.13.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.1.0" % Test,
  "javax.ws.rs" % "javax.ws.rs-api" % "2.0.1",
  "org.keycloak" % "keycloak-adapter-core" % "3.3.0.CR2",
  "org.keycloak" % "keycloak-core" % "3.3.0.CR2",
  "org.keycloak" % "keycloak-admin-client" % "12.0.2"
)
```

Comment: How did you resolve this issue? I am facing same issue

Comment: @AmanVerma did you try to add the dependencies I've listed above?